# webjob error, when load file from Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, blob, storage, azure-webjobs

I have a web job published in a webapp, running Continuous to read file from Azure blob and import data into database.
but have problem when load file from AZure, the issue is not happen in the first time, below is the error message:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(Stream target, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
>      at BankSearch.FileImporter.Services.FileImportService.d__16.MoveNext()

error happen in the line below

```
try
{
    await fileBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream, null, blobRequestOptions, null);
    fileStream.Position = 0;
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    // Exception Handling & Logging
    logger.Error(
            "failed to load the file from Azure blob, file name : >{filename}, error : {error}, {error2}",
            fileToProcess.FileName, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
    //await SendMappingFailedEmail(fileToProcess, failedColumns);
    //return null;
}
```

to get this error:

1. publish the webjob to AZure web app.
2. run webjob to read file1 from blob, works fine.
3. run webjob to read file2 from blob, throw the exception above.
4. publish the webjob again, run web job to read file 2 from blob, works fine.
5. run webjob to read file3 from blob, throw the same exception.

can anyone help me to find what's wrong with the webjob?
the file from the blob is accessible from webjob.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `fileBlob` points to a blob that doesn't exist, given the response code. I recommend stepping through your code line-by-line with the debugger, and make sure you've got the correct container and blob.

Comment: Next to @John 's note, please give us some more relevant code. There are several things we cannot see now, like what type of stream you're using, what the filename is and so on.

Comment: steps to get this error: 1. publish the webjob to AZure web app. 2. run webjob to read file1 from blob, works fine. 3. run webjob to read file2 from blob, throw the exception above. 4. publish the webjob again, run web job to read file 2 from blob, works fine. 5. run webjob to read file3 from blob, throw the same exception

Comment: Thanks @John and Rick I will double check the file blob point to correct container,

Comment: I found the issue , the different file are stored in different blob, and need to Initialize the cloud blob container before read new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue , the different file are stored in different blob, and need to Initialize the cloud blob container before read new files